# Jquery - show div on input hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm try to make a tooltip that doesn't need any 3rd party code. I want to do it in jQuery & CSS.
It needs to support new lines and only show when hovering over an input element.

I don't want to add additional code to the HTML page or add a title to the input field if possible.

I've created an object that includes the text to display, the live object will also contain other values.

```
tooltip = {
    'sitea':    { 'tip': 'Site A Hover' },
    'siteb':    { 'tip': 'Site A Hover' },
    'sitec':    { 'tip': 'Site A Hover' }
}
```

When I hover over an input I want a div to show the text from the object. So far I've got the hover working, but I'm not sure how to do the div and display it only while hovering.

```
$(":input").hover( function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer')
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','auto');
    })
```

I found this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sBtxq/), that seems to work for `td`, is there anyway to use this to show on the input ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is `sitea ,siteb..` ? input id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got his working using the following fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/wjh6va8k/1/

css:

```
.tooltip {
    display: block
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #008800;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

js

```
$(":input").hover( function(e) {
      $('body').append('<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">Tooltip<br>New line</div>').show()
    
    elmTop = $(this).offset().top + 10;
    elmWidth = $(this).width() + 10;
    
    $('#tooltip').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
    $('#tooltip').css( 'top', elmTop  );
    $('#tooltip').css( 'left', elmWidth );

})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this following:

Add this to your css file.

```
div:hover > .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
```

Add this to the javascript file:

```
$('div').append('<div class="div-to-display">yay</div>');
```

Add this new div tag on which you want to display tooltip.

```
<div>newly added div tag (hover to diplay tooltip </div>
```

And of course you can add css and change tooltip as per the requirement.

Comment: thanks but I want to have the hover on an INPUT not DIV